# How to get the csv alias for a thread in Jmeter sharing mode current thread?

Tags: csv, jmeter

Here is my test plan structure.

```
User Login
 Runtime Controller
  while controller !<> EOF
   CSV dataset (items to add)
   search and add to cart
  Click cart.  
  Proceed to check out
  Order submit.
  Beanshell sampler to close CSV
User Logout.
```

I want each thread to read the csv till EOF and add these items to cart, hence I used the sharing 
mode as current thread.Since add to cart and order submission is getting repeated for the test 
duration I am closing the file and resetting the variable after order submit so that next iteration 
will again start to read from beginning.
    The beanshell code is :

```
import org.apache.jmeter.## Heading ##services.FileServer;
FileServer.getFileServer().closeFile("Scripts_Helan\\DSOrderParts.csv");
String pPartNum = vars.get("pPartNum");
vars.put("pPartNum", "");

But when I run the test Jmeter log is showing file name as 

Stored: Scripts_Helan\DSOrderParts.csv Alias: Scripts_Helan\DSOrderParts.csv@1309262272

Don't I have to use the Alias in closeFile? How can I get it?[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get why you are using beanshell code here.

- You can handle the "start all over when done" part with setting up the ***Thread Group*** accordingly
- You can handle that "stop thread at end of file" part with setting up the ***CSV Data Set Config*** accordingly

Please clarify what makes handling the file in beanshell code neccessary.

Comment: In my scenario each thread is only logged in and logged out once. Once logged in the user repeats the steps under runtime controller section for the test duration.So when the thread tries to add items to cart for the second time, since the parameter value is <EOF> it is not going in to the while loop.Hence I added the code to close the file and reset the parameter.I don't want the thread to stop at EOF , I want it to continue with order submit.